# Android Studio Error: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sigabrt

While it doesn't always happen, I occasionally get a fatal error from my Android Application when I leave my application running for long periods of time.

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_OPERATION
A/OpenGLRenderer: GL errors! frameworks/base/libs/hwui/pipeline/skia/SkiaOpenGLPipeline.cpp:126
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 6955 (RenderThread), pid 6934
```

I'm not sure what the error is and therefore not sure how to fix it.

Is there a website that I am missing that shows the error code and signal and explains each different values in more detail?

Please help!

Comment: You mean,When you run the app,your app will be crash?

Comment: It usually crashes when I leave the app running for a few minutes.

Comment: This problem occurs when debugging or running app directly?

Comment: Running the app directly

Comment: This crash happens in all project of android studio or particular app?

Comment: This particular app.

Comment: I think :Try doing all of particular activity work on a background thread instead of the UI thread,
Please refer this link : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr